# How can I initially apply styling after a component mounts but still respect CSS transitions?

Tags: css, reactjs

So I'm trying to add some transitions to my react components but can't seem to get it working in ComponentDidMount().  If I have the styling applied onClick, e.g. height: 100%, it will respect the transition on height.  But if I change the styling in ComponentDidMount() it applies it instantly.

For instance this works:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div
            className="board"
            onClick={() => {this.element.style.opacity = 1}}>
        </div>
    )
}
```

but this doesn't (at least not as intended):

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.element.style.opacity = 1;
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="board"></div>
    )
}
```

Here's the styling:

```css
.board {
    background: darkslateblue;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    padding: 4rem;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

I'm hoping for the transition to be followed but it's ignoring the transition when changing the styling right off the bat.

Comment: Try [react-transition-group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group)

Comment: I think that's probably my best bet I'm thinking

Answer (score 0):

try it, this work fine, define `setInterval`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.element.style.opacity = 1;
      this.element.style.width = "230px";
    },1)
  }
```

Comment: No luck :( I tried to set it to zero and then to one right after as well

Comment: Yes that works but I'm using react, also I already mentioned it works onClick events but not on initial load

Comment: you hoping for the transition to be followed when click toggle? try change`this.state = {
      fade: 1
    };`

Comment: if you want to see the transition, add alert in `componentDidMount() {
    alert("hi");
    this.element.style.opacity = 1;
    this.element.style.width = "230px";
  }`

Comment: it may be necessary to define another life cycle?

Comment: Yeah I think you're right.  Adding alert makes it work so I'm guessing it's the flow of using comonentDidMount.  I don't really understand enough to know why it works like that